# core number of connections must be positive error

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax java driver 3.1.0 to connect to cassandra. I want to connect to local cassandra node always instead of connecting with remote cassandra nodes.

```
public class CassUtil {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(CassUtil.class);
  private Session session;
  private Cluster cluster;

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CassUtil INSTANCE = new CassUtil();
  }

  public static CassUtil getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CassUtil() {
    List<String> servers = TestUtils.HOSTNAMES;
    String username =
        TestUtils.loadCredentialFile().getProperty(TestUtils.USERNAME);
    String password =
        TestUtils.loadCredentialFile().getProperty(TestUtils.PASSWORD);

    // this code throws exception
    PoolingOptions opts = new PoolingOptions();
    opts.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,
        opts.getCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL));

    Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    cluster =
        builder
            .addContactPoints(servers.toArray(new String[servers.size()]))
            .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withPoolingOptions(opts)
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
                    .builder()
                    .withLocalDc(
                        !TestUtils.isProduction() ? "ABC2" : TestUtils.getCurrentLocation()
                            .get().name().toLowerCase()).build())
            .withCredentials(username, password).build();

    try {
      session = cluster.connect("testkeyspace");
    } catch (NoHostAvailableException ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I am running above code, it is throwing me an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: core number of connections must be positive
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(PoolingOptions.java:199)
```

Also I want to make sure that my client always connect with local cassandra nodes and not with any remote cassandra nodes.

Answer (score 2):

`PoolingOptions` can work with different version of protocol (V2, V3, V4) and each version has different defaults. In order to figure out which protocol is best driver must communicate with Cassandra first and then set defaults and until then driver uses `-1`. When you look at `PoolingOptions` this is even wrapped in comments above defaults (where `UNSET` constant is `-1`):

```
// The defaults for these fields depend on the protocol version, which is only known after control connection initialization.
// Yet if the user set them before initialization, we want to keep their values. So we use -1 to mean "uninitialized".
private final int[] coreConnections = new int[]{UNSET, UNSET, 0};
```

When you look at getter you are using it reads from that same array:

```
public int getCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance distance) {
    return coreConnections[distance.ordinal()];
}
```

Which will effectively return `-1` at the time of cluster initialization.

You can explicitly set protocol version which will fill array with right defaults (check DataStax table for versions of Cassandra/DSE and protocol versions on this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/native_protocol/)) or you can set core connection as some desired positive number instead of using getter.

Regarding question for local you can use `LOCAL_ONE/LOCAL_ANY/LOCAL_QUORUM` to prefer local nodes instead of remote (in different DC).

Comment: So what I should do in my client code to fix this problem? And where I should use `LOCAL_ONE`? I am already using HOSTDISTANCE LOCAL, is it not the same thing?

Comment: problem is we may have difference cassandra version in dev as compared to production. I mean they both may not be on same exact version so in this scenario what we should do then?

Comment: Ok I figure it out that we are using `2.0.10` Cassandra version.

Comment: You are using DCAwareLoadBalancingPolicy which will prefer local DC if you write and read queries with LOCAL_ version of query. I would loose part with pooling options since it is not needed (let Cassandra set defaults based on protocol version) and use LOCAL_ when you read/write. If you want to prevent communication with remote DC try using only RoundRobinPolicy instead of DCAware or wrap it in WhiteLabel policy which will filter out only hosts you want.